# C++ function with a viariable number of arguments of a certain type

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor, variadic-templates

I just learned about variadic templates in C++. I implemented it, but I want to know, can it do the following?

If I want a function with a variable number of arguments, I could do that:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
f(Ts... args);
```

But I lose type safety (I don't know the type of the arguments).

What if I know my function needs only `float` as arguments? I want to make sure at compile-time that every argument is the type I want.

So these are my questions:

- Is there a way to force a certain type with variadic templates (something like this)?

  ```cpp
  template <float... Fs>
  f(Fs... args); // unlimited number of arguments but only float
  ```
- If not, is there a way to check it at compile-time? `static_assert(std::is_same<A,B>)` is fine in most cases, but it doesn't work for templated classes (like for my use case):

  ```cpp
  template <typename T, uint16_t dimension>
  class Vector
  {
      template <typename... Ts>
      Vector(Ts... args)
      {
          static_assert(sizeof...(args) == dimension);
          static_assert(std::is_same_v<Ts..., T>()); //doesn't work because Ts will
                                                     //develop into a lot of template 
                                                     //arguments. Just putting Ts doesn't
                                                     //work either.
      }
  }
  ```

Ps: Yes I could use `std::vector` or `std::array` as arguments, but that's not really the point. Plus, I want to keep the beautiful `Vector(2.0, 1.0, 0.0)` syntax, not using curly braces.

Comment: `std::conjunction<std::is_same<float, Ts>...>::value` should tell you if they're all the `float`.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `f(4)` is called? Do you expect this to fail because `4` is not a `float`? Or do you expect to have `4` converted to the parameter `4.0f`?

Comment: float is not really the problem , the problem is when the type is templated (like in my Vector class example)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would like it to fail, really making sure it is the same type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler supports C++ 20 then you can write for example

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, uint16_t dimension>
class Vector
{
public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    Vector( Ts &&... args ) requires ( sizeof...( args ) == dimension ) && std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, std::decay_t<Ts>>...>
    {
    }
};

//...

Vector<float, 5> v( 1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f, 5.5f );
```

Or as **@HolyBlackCat** wrote in a comment you may also write

```
template <typename T, uint16_t dimension>
class Vector
{
public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    Vector( std::same_as<T> auto ...args ) requires( sizeof...( args ) == dimension )
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Can be shortened to `Vector(std::same_as<T> auto ...args) requires(sizeof...(args) == dimension)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, @HolyBlackCat's version works, but yours gives me compile errors... Thanks for the neat answers anyway!

Comment: @EloiGG I checked the both versions and they work.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow okay gotta investigate on this one :)

Comment: @EloiGG I have updated the first example.:)

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T, uint16_t dimension>
class MyVector
{
  public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    MyVector(Ts... args)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == dimension);
        static_assert((std::is_same<T,Ts>::value && ...) );
    }
};
```

Can also use the unary right fold expression as provided in C++17
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

This essentially does

```
std::is_same<T,Ts_1>::value && ( std::is_same<T,Ts_2>::value && ... std::is_same<T,Ts_n>::value ) ...)
```

And works also when the parameter pack Ts is empty. Quote from the reference link:

```
" Logical AND (&&). The value for the empty pack is true"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of fixed vector as in your case, there is an alternative with [`std::index sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence):

```
// helper for folding
template <typename T, std::size_t /*ignored*/>
using always_t = T;

template <typename T, typename Seq>
class VectorImpl;

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
class VectorImpl<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
public:
    VectorImpl(always_t<T, Is>... args); // equivalent to VectorImpl(T arg1, T arg2, ..)
    // ...
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using Vector = VectorImpl<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
```